# Determining a time period

Tags: android

I want to make something in a specific time period. For instance, I'll show a message in my application from 6pm to 8pm everyday. I'll do it in a service. Which code should I use and could you please give a sample? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

I would look into using Android Notifications along with AlarmManager to handle the repeating.

Particularly [setRepeating in AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) to call the service and creating the actual Notification in the onReceive of your service.

Comment: Actually, the process what I'll do is different from notifications, but AlarmManager may be what I look for. I'm looking at it. Thank you.

Comment: Yes AlarmManager is the best way to handle repeating calls to a service. If not notifications you can create anything you want such a an AlertDialog or a simple toast from within the service.

Answer (score 2):

You should use an AlarmManager

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

you can find tons of examples online